# A question about the "segementation fault"

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I am reading the book: *TinyML: Machine Learning with TensorFlow on Arduino, and Ultra-Low Power Micro-Controllers* and doing the relevant tutorials on Macbook M1.

I encounter one problem when I execute **make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile hello_world**. I get the executable file in the path: **gen/osx_x86_64/bin/hello_world**.

While executing **./hello_world** in terminal, I get an error:

*zsh: segmentation fault hello_world*

I fix this problem by changing **constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 2 * 1024;** to **constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 3 * 1024;** in the file **main_functions.cc**.

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/hello_world/main_functions.h"

#include "tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/hello_world/constants.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/hello_world/output_handler.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/hello_world/sine_model_data.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/kernels/all_ops_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/micro_error_reporter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/version.h"

// Globals, used for compatibility with Arduino-style sketches.
namespace {
tflite::ErrorReporter* error_reporter = nullptr;
const tflite::Model* model = nullptr;
tflite::MicroInterpreter* interpreter = nullptr;
TfLiteTensor* input = nullptr;
TfLiteTensor* output = nullptr;
int inference_count = 0;

// Create an area of memory to use for input, output, and intermediate arrays.
// Finding the minimum value for your model may require some trial and error.
#################################################################
constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 3 * 1024; // used to be 2 * 1024
#################################################################
uint8_t tensor_arena[kTensorArenaSize];
}  // namespace
```

Can anyone give me some hints on this error? Thank you in advance~